# Check whether cell contents are in a list on another tab

Tags: vba, excel

I've looked high and low and I can't find anything that works for me.

I have a list of values on a tab that I have going through a for loop.

The loop finds the current value on the active tab, in another tab and exports some data - this is all working fine. However I am trying to add some validation to the process - In the loop I want to make sure the value currently being worked on is actually a value present in the range I'm playing with. If it's a valid value, do the business and change the cell green, if not, change to red and proceed with the next iteration.

I know in my mind how I want to have it look but I can't find anything to help me do this.

The pseudo code would be

```
for i=1 to lastRowInRange

    if activeCellValue is NOT a value in column N on tab "Data" then

        change cell colour red and do nothing else

    else

       do lots of exporty things

       change cell colour to green

next i
```

I tried the intersect method but couldn't get it to work

Any help is massively appreciated!

Mike

Comment: So... Whats your question? Whats the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Do you have a ***specific* programming related question**?  I'd suggest checking out "[help/on-topic]" as well as "[ask]".  There are also great tips from Jon Skeet available [here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/).  You can always [edit] your post to add more information.

Comment: I'd suggest you look a little harder.

Comment: I dont know why this question is closed. OP's question looks quite fine today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the code below will help you do what you expect, this will look for values in Column A and search for that value in Column N, if found make the interior color of that given cell Green if not found then make the cell Red:

```
Sub test()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column A

For i = 1 To LastRow 'loop from row 1 to last
    Set FindValue = Worksheets("Data").Range("N:N").Find(What:=ws.Cells(i, "A"), lookat:=xlWhole)
    'above search for value from Column A in Column N of Sheet Data
    If FindValue Is Nothing Then 'if not found
        ws.Cells(i, "A").Interior.Color = 255 ' not found then make cell Red
    Else 'if found
        ws.Cells(i, "A").Interior.Color = 5287936 ' found then make cell Green
       'do lots of exporty things
    End If
    Set FindValue = Nothing
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: @MikeyB could you mark my response as an answer if it has helped? Thanks.

Comment: This worked perfectly after I removed the 'Not' from the if statement - the double negative meant that it would export empty files for values that didn't exist and skip over the values that did (and color them red). Thank you very much for your help though - this is exactly what I was after!